# Comparing Abbreviated words based on mapping file in pandas and python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following dataframe df

```
ID  Location   Name_x             Name_y
1   Paris      Paris Systems     Paris Sys
2   London     London Pvt        London Private
3   Texas      Texas Instruments Texas Instr
4   Italy      Italy Assoc       Italy Private
```

I have another mapping dataframe containing the mapping of abbreviations
df_map

```
word   abbreviation
Private     Pvt
System      Sys   
Instruments Instr
Association Assoc
```

When I compare Name_x and Name_y column of the dataframe df, the column should match if the word is mapped to the correct  abbreviation.
For example,in the dataframe df following should be the output.

```
ID  Location   Name_x             Name_y            Identical
1   Paris      Paris Systems     Paris Sys          yes
2   London     London Pvt        London Private     yes
3   Texas      Texas Instruments Texas Instr        yes
4   Italy      Italy Assoc       Italy Private      no
```

How can I do that?
I am trying to do the following

```
word_lst=df_map["word"].tolist()
abbreviation_lst=df_map["abbreviation"].tolist()
for index,row in df.iterrorws():
    if any( word in word_lst in row["Name_x"])
```

I am not sure what to do to match these to find of the strings in Name_x and Name_y are identical as the abbreviation can be in either Name_x and Name_y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `pandas.Series.str.replace`.

Make the second dataframe as `dict`:

```
d = df2.set_index("word").squeeze().to_dict()
```

Then use `replace`:

```
keys = "|".join(d.keys())
cols = ["Name_x", "Name_y"]
for c in cols:
    df[c] = df[c].str.replace(keys, lambda x: d[x.group(0)], regex=True)
```

Output:

```
   ID Location       Name_x       Name_y
0   1    Paris   Paris Syss    Paris Sys
1   2   London   London Pvt   London Pvt
2   3    Texas  Texas Instr  Texas Instr
3   4    Italy  Italy Assoc    Italy Pvt
```

You can then compare and assign the result:

```
df["Identical"] = df["Name_x"].eq(df["Name_y"])
```

Final Output:

```
   ID Location       Name_x       Name_y  Identical
0   1    Paris   Paris Syss    Paris Sys      False
1   2   London   London Pvt   London Pvt       True
2   3    Texas  Texas Instr  Texas Instr       True
3   4    Italy  Italy Assoc    Italy Pvt      False
```

Comment: I would probably match exact words, which is little extra effort since you’re already using regex.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the transformation as follows:

- split into words
- use your second dataframe to replace words by abbreviations
- join again

Doing all that with pandas vectorized operations looks like:

```
>>> words = df['Name_x'].str.split(expand=True)
>>> words
        0            1
0   Paris      Systems
1  London          Pvt
2   Texas  Instruments
3   Italy        Assoc
>>> repl = words.transform(lambda s: s.replace(df_abbr.set_index('word')['abbreviation']))
>>> repl
        0        1
0   Paris  Systems
1  London      Pvt
2   Texas    Instr
3   Italy    Assoc
>>> abbr
0    Paris Systems
1       London Pvt
2      Texas Instr
3      Italy Assoc
dtype: object
>>> df['Name_y'].eq(abbr)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
>>> df.join([df['Name_y'].eq(abbr).map({True: 'yes', False: 'no'}).rename('Identical'), abbr.rename('abbreviated Name_x')])
   ID Location             Name_x          Name_y Identical abbreviated Name_x
0   1    Paris      Paris Systems       Paris Sys        no      Paris Systems
1   2   London         London Pvt  London Private        no         London Pvt
2   3    Texas  Texas Instruments     Texas Instr       yes        Texas Instr
3   4    Italy        Italy Assoc   Italy Private        no        Italy Assoc
```

As you can see the first row doesn’t much because you don’t have an abbreviation for `Systems`, just `System`. With the second row, `Name_x` is abbreviated but `Name_y` contains the full name (if you want to allow for that rather than check if `Name_y` is the abbreviation of `Name_x`, you should apply the abbreviation process to both columns before comparing). Finally row 3 is abbreviated as expected and row 4 contains different words.